# forkjoinpool execute non-recursive tasks and join all

Tags: java, parallel-processing, forkjoinpool

I have a list of objects stored in an array, each with a simple (non-recursive) task to compute.

I want to execute those method of each object in parallel, then wait for all of them to finish before continuing.

May I know if the code below will do what I want? Are there any problems that I overlook?

Thanks.

```
public void calculateAllFitnessParallel() 
{
    ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool();

    for (int i = 0; i < currentPopulation; i++)
        pool.execute(individuals[i]); // execute these in parallel

    // close pool and wait
    pool.shutdown();
    for (int i = 0; i < currentPopulation; i++)
        individuals[i].join();

    // need all parallel tasks to finish before this
    findFittest();

}
```

Comment: If you dont need recursivity I strongly suggest you avoid `ForkJoinPool` :http://coopsoft.com/ar/CalamityArticle.html . Use something like `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(poolSize)` instead.